# Why do floating point operations yield different results in go

Tags: go, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

Here's the sample code in go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func mult32(a, b float32) float32 { return a*b }
func mult64(a, b float64) float64 { return a*b }


func main() {
    fmt.Println(3*4.3)                  // A1, 12.9
    fmt.Println(mult32(3, 4.3))         // B1, 12.900001
    fmt.Println(mult64(3, 4.3))         // C1, 12.899999999999999

    fmt.Println(12.9 - 3*4.3)           // A2, 1.8033161362862765e-130
    fmt.Println(12.9 - mult32(3, 4.3))  // B2, -9.536743e-07
    fmt.Println(12.9 - mult64(3, 4.3))  // C2, 1.7763568394002505e-15

    fmt.Println(12.9 - 3*4.3)                               // A4, 1.8033161362862765e-130
    fmt.Println(float32(12.9) - float32(3)*float32(4.3))    // B4, -9.536743e-07
    fmt.Println(float64(12.9) - float64(3)*float64(4.3))    // C4, 1.7763568394002505e-15

}
```

Results differences between lines A1, B1 and C1 are understandable. However, starting from A2 to C2 magic comes. Result from neither of B2 nor C2 matches the result from A2 line. The same is true for lines x2 (x = A, B or C) - but the outputs of x2 and x4 are the same.

Just to be sure let's print the results in the binary form.

```
    fmt.Printf("%b\n", 3*4.3)                   // A11, 7262054399134925p-49
    fmt.Printf("%b\n", mult32(3, 4.3))          // B11, 13526631p-20
    fmt.Printf("%b\n", mult64(3, 4.3))          // C11, 7262054399134924p-49

    fmt.Printf("%b\n", 12.9 - 3*4.3)            // A12, 4503599627370496p-483
    fmt.Printf("%b\n", 12.9 - mult32(3, 4.3))   // B12, -8388608p-43
    fmt.Printf("%b\n", 12.9 - mult64(3, 4.3))   // C12, 4503599627370496p-101

    fmt.Printf("%b\n", 12.9 - 3*4.3)                                // A14, 4503599627370496p-483
    fmt.Printf("%b\n", float32(12.9) - float32(3)*float32(4.3))     // B14, -8388608p-43
    fmt.Printf("%b\n", float64(12.9) - float64(3)*float64(4.3))     // C14, 4503599627370496p-101
```

Some facts from the code above (one in the bin form):

1. There is difference between line A11 and C11 (last digit - just before the exponent).
2. Lines A12 and C12 are almost the same (except the exponen!!!), the same can be observed between line A14 and C14.

And here the questions come:

1. How computations of bare (naked :)) numbers are performed? (computations in every Axx line)
2. Are they performed by compiler/whatever?
3. If yes, then why are they different? Optimisation?
4. Are they computed in some system which differs from IEE-754?
5. If yes, why so?
6. Is achieving more accurate precision justifiest such approach?

Code has been tested on 64bit linux under both "go run" and "go build" (go1.0.3), and also on that site: http://tour.golang.org/

Comment: This question, currently closed as of March 5th, 2024, is deemed to lack focus, though its recent title refinement addresses this concern. However, I disagree with the rationale behind its closure, which cites the need for more focus. Per Stack Overflow guidelines (https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), the sub-questions within the query indeed concentrate on distinct aspects of the broader issue: the precision of floating-point operations in the Go language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [Constants](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants):

   > - Numeric constants represent values of arbitrary precision and do not overflow.
   > - Represent integer constants with at least 256 bits.
   > - Represent floating-point constants, including the parts of a complex constant, with a mantissa of at least 256 bits and a signed exponent of at least 32 bits.
2. Yes, by the compiler for compile time constants.
3. Yes, they're different: More precision is involved. See 1.
4. Yes, see 1.
5. To minimize accumulation of floating point errors for multi-term floating point constant expressions.
6. Of course yes. Can achieving *lower* precision be ever a goal? It's enough that run-time floating point operations are intrinsically imperfect, no need to add more imprecision from constant expressions.

Comment: There is a case for lower, standard-conforming precision - consistent, predictable results from different hardware. That can both reduce the amount of testing, and make testing simpler.

Comment: The 256+32 bits floating point constants are computed in code, no HW (directly) involved. The final value of C1+C2+C2 always _is used_ in a standard-conforming precision when emited by the compiler as assembler code instruction. The high precision exists only as an "ideal number" _before_ substituted into expressions. So there's no problem here. If you want lower precision - it's easy: `const k float32 = 1.23456`, it has exactly 32 bits of total precision. Same for eg. `const z float64 = 1/3`. There's no good reason for lower precision of "ideal" numbers and the used one is controlled by you.

Answer (score 0):

> Represent floating-point constants, including the parts of a complex constant, with a mantissa of at least 256 bits and a signed exponent of at least 32 bits.

Note that [Go 1.8](https://beta.golang.org/doc/go1.8) (currently in beta in Q4 2016, released in Q1 2017) changes that definition:

> The language specification now only requires that implementations support **up to 16-bit exponents** in floating-point constants.
> This does not affect either the “[`gc`](https://beta.golang.org/cmd/compile/)” or `gccgo` compilers, both of which still support 32-bit exponents.

That comes from [change 17711](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/17711/)

> ### `spec`: require 16 bit minimum exponent in constants rather than 32
>
> A 16bit binary exponent permits a constant range covering roughly the range from 7e-9865 to 7e9863 which is more than enough for any practical and hypothetical constant arithmetic.
>
> Furthermore, until recently `cmd/compile` could not handle very large exponents correctly anyway; i.e., the chance that any real programs (but for tests that explore corner cases) are affected are close to zero.
>
> Finally, restricting the minimum supported range significantly reduces the implementation complexity in an area that hardly matters in reality for new or alternative spec-compliant implementations that don't or cannot rely on pre-existing arbitratry precision arithmetic packages that support a 32bit exponent range.
>
> This is technically a language change but for the reasons mentioned above this is unlikely to affect any real programs, and certainly not programs compiled with the gc or gccgo compilers as they currently support up to 32bit exponents.

See [issue 13572](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13572) mentioning that:

> In Go 1.4 the compiler rejected exponents larger than 10000 (due to knowing the code didn't work for larger exponents) without any complaint from users.
>
> In earlier versions of Go, large exponents were silently mishandled, again without any complaint from users.